# Composer while 'docker-compose' with mount bind

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, composer-php, bind

I try to build a docker-compose project for a php application beside a database, which is automatically deployed on a developer machine. It's not a problem, but where it's stuck is the `composer-install`.

I want to have a directory from the host computer which is bind into the container, so developer are able to change code and are able to see it immediately in the docker instance. That means

1. Deploy a container with PHP and a webserver
2. Deploy the database
3. Bind the local source directory into the PHP container
4. Execute a composer-install in that directory

The directory tree is like

```
/
-php
-- src
-- Dockerfile
-postgres
-- Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
```

I attached snippets from my `docker-compose.yml` and the PHP `Dockerfile`, anyone has an idea why it fails or see the problem in the order or something else or even can me explain what I have to notice? That would be great!

Dockerfile:

```
FROM xy

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php \
        && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/ \
        && ln -s /usr/local/bin/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

COPY ./src /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html/

RUN composer install --prefer-source --no-interaction
```

Docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
    php:
        build: ./php
        container_name: "php"
        volumes:
             - ./php/src:/var/www/html

    postgres:
        image: postgres:10.4-alpine
        container_name: "postgres"
```

Comment: Any error message would be useful

Comment: The issue might be that the `composer install` command is running and terminates correctly but there is nothing to do afterwards for the container? I had issues with a postgres-container before because it started slower than my php-container. Use `depends_on` in the php-container config to start them in the correct order maybe

Comment: When I understood an article [1] I read correctly, I can do whatever I want in the building process in a directory e. g. '/var/www/html'. When I mount a volume on that (even when the mount happens before the composer-install) directory, everything from the layer before is gone and it has a kind of priority.

[1] https://www.phase2technology.com/blog/bending-your-containers-bind-mounts